# sockettimeoutexception causing app hang

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I am trying to ping the server in asynk task but the i am getting sockettimeout exception when i enter a invalid port number so that causes app hang. Post method of the asynk task is never called & app does not respond may i know why it happening. I am using the following code for this purpose.

```
    private class UrlDataProvider3 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{

    String ret="";
    int checkStatus;
    Boolean exception=false;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) 
    {

        HttpURLConnection con = null;

        try 
          { 

            Log.i("RAE", "urlData"+url[0]);
            HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
             con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url[0]).openConnection();
                 con.setRequestMethod("POST");
              con.setConnectTimeout(20000);

          }


        catch (IOException e)
          {
            if(e.toString().contains("java.net.SocketTimeoutException:"))
            {
                 log.i("Hello","Exception Occurs");
                 return null;
            }

          }
    return ret;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.i("RAE"," Asyc finished");

}
```

Comment: return null in `IOException`

Comment: catch SocketTimeoutException

Comment: yes i did but app is hanging

Comment: Exceptions do not cause applications to hang. Your question is unintelligible.

Comment: so what is causing ?

Comment: where is it hanging on ? did you try checking the thread stack ? http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html

Comment: Yes. I tried showing ,t asyk task #1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need catch `SocketTimeoutException` and a *return statement* in `catch` block then only it will go to `onPostExecute`

```
catch (SocketTimeoutException ste)
{
    return null;
}
catch (IOException e)
{
       return null;

}
```

And handle it in `onPostExecute`

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

   super.onPostExecute(result);
   Log.i("RAE"," Asyc finished");
   if (result !=null)
   {
       // your code
   }
   else
   {
        // You got an exception
   }
```

Comment: debug and tell me it is going in *Catch* block. Check logcat  also

Comment: it is going in the catch block & print my statement

Comment: is it going in SocketTimeoutException ??

Comment: I have checked it .when any exception occur it catches the socket time out exception.but app odes not respond . what may be the reason ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66305/discussion-between-sweetwisher--and-tarun-sharma).

Comment: 12-06 12:32:34.945: I/RAE(15596): FirstLogin
12-06 12:32:34.955: I/RAE(15596): CheckFirst
12-06 12:32:34.955: I/RAE(15596): checkUrlhttp://www.example.com:8090/folder
12-06 12:32:34.965: I/RAE(15596): urlDatahttp://www.example.com:8090/folder
12-06 12:32:55.067: I/RAE(15596): inside socket
12-06 12:32:55.067: I/RAE(15596): after urldata1